# passing comobox value to another form not working

Tags: vb.net

Hi in the below from grid displaying class names those are coming from database and passing cell value to another form.but it's displaying but while updating the class name then it's taking empty value as a class

want to update the class name pass the same value to the database otherwise want old class name.but,it's nothing working simply it's updating an empty value in db.

Form1.vb

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
        Dim form As New update
        form.ComboBox1.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString         
        form.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

Form2.vb:

```
Private Sub showItems()
        Button3.Visible = False

        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source="
        dataFile = "D:\jyothi school\School Management\School Management\AddStudent.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim query = "Select * From Add_Student "
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, myConnection)

        da.Fill(dt)

        'checking the result[user_name] = '" & user_name.Text & "'
        ' If userFound = True Then
        'Add_Fee.Show()

        'End If'
        Me.ComboBox1.SelectedValue = ComboBox1.SelectedText
        ' Else
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("NURSERY")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("LKG")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("UKG")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("1ST")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("2ND")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("3RD")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("4TH")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("5TH")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("6TH")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("7TH")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("8TH")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("9TH")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("10TH")
        Selected_Class = ComboBox1.SelectedText
        myConnection.Close()




    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        provider1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source="
        dataFile1 = "D:\jyothi school\School Management\School Management\AddStudent.accdb"
        connString1 = provider1 & dataFile1
        myConnection1.ConnectionString = connString1
        myConnection1.Open()


        Dim str1 As String
        str1 = "Update [Add_Student] set [StudentName] = '" & TextBox4.Text & "',[Mobile No] = " & TextBox3.Text & ",[Class] = '" & Selected_Class & "',[Total Fee] = " & TextBox5.Text & ",[Old Fee] = " & TextBox2.Text & ",[Deposit] = " & TextBox6.Text & ",[New_Deposit]= " & TextBox8.Text & ",[Pending Fee] = " & TextBox7.Text & " Where [StudentId] = " & TextBox1.Text & ""
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str1, myConnection1)
        Try
            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("Successfully Updated Students Details")
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
                myConnection1.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Specifically what values are you talking about?  When you step through this code in your debugger, where do you first encounter an "empty value" that you expect should not be empty?  Where do you expect the value to come from?

Comment: want selected class value what is coming from grid.but its taking empty.ex:class:Lkg want same class name. using combox i had selected 4th means want to pass 4th

Comment: can u please tell me david

Comment: Tell you *what*?  You need to be more specific about the problem.  Use the debugger that's available to you.  When you step through you logic in the debugger, line by line, where does it first differ from what you expect?

Comment: from form1 form.ComboBox1.Text this value want to pass to form2 want to display the name of the class4

Comment: Sorry, but you're failing to describe the problem.  Perhaps someone else will be able to guess what you're trying to describe, but it's not making any sense to me.  The only advice I can give you at this point is to *actually use a debugger* instead of just pointing at the code and describing what you want.

Comment: while debugging am getting form.ComboBox1.Text value this value how to pass to next form this is my question

Comment: The first snippet passes a value to a combo box on another form (a bad idea) but the rest of the code doesnt seem to use it anywhere.  It seems like the update statement ought to use it in a WHERE clause but it just gkues a bunch of other controls into the SQL (a very very bad idea).  IF the first form has a DT with all the students, the second form could share the datasource and reduce the juggling and SQL and code in general

Comment: can u please edit my code where did mistake

Comment: Ahh, I see it now.  There is a great deal wrong in that code.  If the cbo class list is static (hard coded), then add them in the designer.  `SelectedValue` is the wrong thing to try to set; a UI control is not a variable.  Expose a public property on the form and use it to pass the value.  Then set the SelectedIndex.  Always use SQL parameters and you are going to want to use a WHERE clause in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

*If* I understand you correctly, in this method:

```
DataGridView1_Click
```

You want to pass this value:

```
form.ComboBox1.Text
```

To this form:

```
Dim form As New update
```

If that's the case, there are a couple ways to do it.  One approach could be to add that value to the form's constructor.  If this is the only constructor, the value becomes required by the form.  If it's optional, make multiple constructors (one with the value and one without).

The new constructor would then set a class-level value on that form.  Something like this:

```
Private myValue As String

Public Sub New(ByVal Value As String)
    myValue = Value
End Sub
```

Then, when you create an instance of that form, provide the value to the *constructor* instead of trying to directly set a *control* on that form:

```
Dim form As New update(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString)
form.ShowDialog()
```

This should pass the value to the `update` form.  (Another option could be to expose a public property instead of a constructor parameter.  Personal preference, really.)  **However**, what do you then *do* with that value?  If you need to set it to a `ComboBox` selected value, do that in the `Load()` event of the `update` form.  *After* the `ComboBox` has been populated with possible values.  But, to be honest, the code you're showing for "form 2" doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.  Especially the part where you add values to a `ComboBox`.  But if you just need this string value on that form, it would now be available in the `myValue` class-level variable.